# WRB (water resistant barrier) detail at eave/rake/peak of shed roofline

Tags: framing, waterproofing

This question pertains to the proper detailing of WRB at the roofline of wood-frame, shed-roofed, new construction, *without* rafter-tail overhang.

I've found little by way of Google. I've found an eave detail that helps, but nothing for the peak and rake sides.

The plan currently is to cut rafters close to the top-plate, set unvented blocks and both pseudo-fascia and fascia boards.

My current thinking is that the drip edge will flash over the fascia boards and that the WRB should tuck behind the fascia board(s).

I keep feeling that a peel-and-stick membrane would be a good idea at this interface, but can't puzzle out how or find a relevant drawing detail.

Comment: When I say "ridge", I mean the high side of a shed roof.  I'll try to re-word the question after work. Thanks for the tip on not running the drain plain behind the fascia.  What I'm asking is: (1) How/Where to terminate the wall's WRB at the roofline?; and, (2) How/With what material (besides drip-edge metal flashing) to waterproof the corner between the roof plane and the wall plane?

Comment: I'd want a drip edge regardless. You can't really have a fascia and have it all waterproof without one.